# Magento 2: It does not redirect me correctly

Tags: magento2, redirect

I have different store views, one with code `'en'` (this works) and one with code `'es_es'` (this does not work and redirects me to the home).

**This is the condition that redirects:**

```
if ($result[0] == self::HTTP_CODE_OK) {
                            $this->sendEmailSuccessCreateRma($result[1]);
                            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('RMA was created successfully'));
                            $this->_redirect('sap/rma/index');
                        } else {
                            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($result[1]);
                        }
```

**And this statement in the`phtml`:**

```
 <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit" class="action primary" data-role="rma-submit">
                        <span><?= __('Submit Request') ?></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the following class to your construct function:

> \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager

and then use the following code for correct url for redirection:

```
$url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('sap/rma/index');
$this->_redirect($url);
```

Comment: Magento returns a blank page. I do not know where to see the error, the syntax is correct :(

Comment: can you check the log?

Comment: What is the path of log file? In this case, var / log of magento do not show me any error

Comment: magento_root/var/log/ this is the only path for magento logs. Enable php error so that you can see the errors for the website.

Comment: Yes i know, but it does not show me any error any of the logs